# How to slide a plotted line in matlab figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am plotting a sin and cosine using below code:

```
x = 0 : 0.1 : 2*pi ;
y1 = sin (x) ;
y2 = cos (x) ;
figure ;
plot(x,y1) ;
hold ;
plot(x,y2,'r')
```

I want to move/slide the line corresponding to sin in order to overlay on top of line corresponding to cos and want to achieve it without moving pan. I searched ob web but unable to find a simple solution.

Comment: Not sure to understand just add a phase no (3*pi/2 or pi/2) ?

Comment: Actually, I need sliding functionality. Above code is just to depict the problem.

Comment: Ho so a dynamical GUI that use a callback to shift the phase according to your mouse ?

Comment: yes.I need that kind of functionality but do not want to re-plot the data. I think, there is way to move or slide the plotted line. I have seen such functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can plot your 2 sinus/cosinus within a function, then use a callback to update your plot, here I update the phase of the sinus plot in the callback function `call_S`:

```
function [] = slider_plot()
  % Plot different plots according to slider location.
  S.fh = figure('position',[300 300 300 300],....
                'resize','off');    
  S.x = 0:.01:4*pi;  %range.         
  S.ax = axes('unit','pix',...
              'position',[20 80 260 210]);
  S.sin = plot(S.x,sin(S.x),'r'); %sinus phase will move
  hold on
  S.cos = plot(S.x,cos(S.x),'b');       
  S.sl = uicontrol('style','slide',...
                   'position',[20 10 260 30],...
                   'min',0,'max',3*pi/2,'val',0,... %default phase = 0
                   'sliderstep',[0.1 0.1],...
                   'callback',{@call_S,S});  
function [] = call_S(varargin)
  % Callback for the phase slider.
  [h,S] = varargin{[1,3]};  % calling handle and data structure.
  set(S.sin,'ydata',sin(S.x + get(h,'value'))) %set the new phase
```

I use a slider in this case, but you could also use the position of your mouse to determine the new phase.

Result:

[image]

And you can move the slider to shift the phase:

[image]

Comment: Nice and Thanks. It is not exactly same solution which I am looking for because actually, I do not have access to function but have x and y1 and y2

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not have access to function" ? will be hard to achieve such a result without using a callback.

Comment: I have data from sampled data from 2x experiments. Is there a way to move plotted line instead of re-plotting.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @obchardon:

Below is updated version of his code which meet my requirements:

```
function [] = slider_plot2()
x = 0 : 0.1 : 4*pi ;
y1 = sin (x) ;
y2 = cos (x) ;
  % Plot different plots according to slider location.
  S.fh = figure('position',[300 300 500 500],....
                'resize','off');    
  S.x = x;  %range.   
  S.y2 = y2  ;
  S.ax = axes('unit','pix',...
              'position',[30 80 460 410]);
  S.line2 = plot(S.x,y2,'r'); %sinus phase will move
  hold on
  S.line1 = plot(S.x,y1,'b');       
  S.sl = uicontrol('style','slide',...
                   'position',[20 10 260 30],...
                   'min',1,'max',length(x),'val',1,... %default phase = 0
                   'sliderstep',[1 1],...
                   'callback',{@call_S,S});  
function [] = call_S(varargin)
  % Callback for the phase slider.
  [h,S] = varargin{[1,3]};  % calling handle and data structure.
  currentPosition = floor(get(h,'value'))  ;
  ydata = S.y2(currentPosition:end) ;
  xdata = S.x(1:end-currentPosition+1)  ;
 set(S.line2,'xdata',xdata,'ydata',ydata) %set the new phase
 %set( S.line2,'ydata',ydata) %set the new phase
```